# How would I interpret Java code from a String?

Tags: java, string

I have gone through many of other people's questions, and I still haven't found an answer.

I want to interpret a String as Java code in Java, not as JavaScript.
Also, if at all possible, I want to link a method to it so that when it is interpreted it leads to that method.

Is it possible? If so, how would I do this?

Comment: Can you please explain what are you looking for by using some example .. it is not clear

Comment: I am looking for something to interpret code in a string, like this: `"Math.cbrt(d);"` or like this `"cubeRoot(double n)"`

Comment: So to clarify, you are looking for a way to parse and execute Java code that is passed in as a string to your program?

Comment: Precisely what I want.

Comment: @ZldProductions You can edit your Question to improve it by adding the example strings and alternate wording seen in these comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

http://www.beanshell.org/

or the Java Compiler API

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html

or Java 9's JShell and REPL

https://blogs.oracle.com/java/entry/jshell_and_relp_in_java

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for, I will test it when I can.